# Write to a file, while in a function in R

Tags: r, function, file-io, file-handling

I want to write a dataframe to a file.

It works like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = xalues, y = yalues)
write.csv(df, 'file.csv')
```

But it does not work when I put it in a function:

```
writing<-function(df){
write.csv(df, 'file.csv')
}
df <- data.frame(x = xalues, y = yalues)
writing(df)
```

This is my whole function:

```
gccount <- function(bestand){  
  library(dict)
  library(stringr)
  bieb<-dict()
  for (i in bestand){
    for (j in i){
      titel<-grepl(">Rosalind",j)
      if (titel==TRUE){
        bieb[[j]]<-""
        bewaar<-j
      }
      else if (titel==FALSE){
        vorige<-bieb[[bewaar]]
        if (vorige==""){
          bieb[[bewaar]]<-j
        }
        else if (vorige!=""){
          bieb[[bewaar]]<-paste(vorige,j,sep = "")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  bieb$items()
  gccbieb<-dict()
  for (naam in bieb$keys()){
    waarde<-bieb[[naam]]
    g<-str_count(waarde,"G")
    c<-str_count(waarde,"C")
    gcc<-100/nchar(waarde)*(g+c)
    gccbieb[[naam]]<-gcc
  }

  
  keys<-gccbieb$keys()
  values<-gccbieb$values()
  sleutels<-c()
  gaten<-c()
  for (key in keys){
    sleutels<-c(sleutels, key)
  }
  for (value in values){
    gaten<-c(gaten, value)
  }
  
  df <- data.frame(x = sleutels, y = gaten)
  write.csv(df, 'gc.csv')
}
bestand<-read.csv('Rosalind.csv', header = FALSE, sep = ".")
gccount(bestand)
```

I don't get a file, but when I split it into two different functions, one to make the dictionary `gccbieb`, and one to write a file, I do get a file.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: i do not get an error message, it just won't write a file, i tried restarting Rstudio etc but that doesn't help either

Answer (score 1):

I think this function is working perfectly well, but the folder it writes the file in is another one that you are expecting.

Try to write the full path of "file.csv" or look into your current working directory which you can identify by `getwd()`

EDIT: can you try with   `df <<- data.frame(x = sleutels, y = gaten)` instead of `<-` ?
By the way, what version of R are you using? I have the error `package ‘dict’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)`, if the solution proposed is not working, try to give us a reproducible example.

Comment: i tried both the options, but it still only writes the file when it is not in a function

Comment: try adding `getwd()` to your function, so it will show you where the file is written to.